# Get keywords from google organic search

Tags: php, analytics

In the good old times I could use PHP to retrieve from the QUERY_STRING the keyword the user typed at Google before click my link (or I could simply use the REFERRER). Nowadays Google does not provide that anymore (except if you use ADWORDS cause you can set parameters in the URL that tells you exactly what the user typed).

So I've been using Google Search Console (old Google Webmaster Tools) to keep track of my rankings. It's a good tool but it does not provide the most important information: which keywords generated conversino at my website so I could know the most effective ones.

Daily my domain receives around 300 visitors from Google (my company sells tires) but I see in the KEYWORK LIST (provided by Search Console) looots of keywords that looks good and others that dont look that much good. BUT IT'S FREAKING hard to tell which ones are really converting into paying customers.

So I decided to ask you: is there some "conversion" tracking that I can install in my website (just like AdWords has) everytime a user clicks the CONTACT form so in the Search Console or in Analytics I can know for sure which keywords are bringing the most valued customers?

Answer (score 2):

Since the Google Secure Search Update in 2011, there Google switched to https (first just for Users logged in to the Google Account - now for all) you don't see your Keywords in Analytics.

There are some solutions:

1. use the Search Console (here you get a idea about your rankings but not about conversion or behavioral metrics of each keyword)
2. there are some workarounds you could use. For example https://blog.kissmetrics.com/unlock-keyword-not-provided/
3. There are some Tools like https://keyword-hero.com They provide you the keywords again in Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics has some options to track visitor events on your site, including conversions and sales. I haven't worked with Analytics recently, but I believe you can generate reports on the relation between search keywords and those events.

Unfortunately, as Google no longer forwards most search queries to web sites in referers, other web analytics services cannot track this same data. As far as I'm aware, Google Analytics is the *only* way to correlate Google search queries to on-page actions.

Comment: It was good to know from you that GA now allows watching individual users behaviour instead of grouped. Untortunatelly it does not tell which keywoard brought the user ;(